# How do I <embed> svg and scale it like an img

Tags: svg

I just like images I want to separate the picture from the page. I can take a 1024x768 image and do this

```
<img src="1024x768.jpg" width="400" height="300"/>
```

or I can do this

```
<img src="1024x768.jpg" style="width:400px; height:300px"/>
```

and the image will be scaled not cropped. How do I do the same with svg? Note: I don't want to embed the svg directly into the page. That would be as stupid as using dataURLs for all my images. My artists edit images, other people edit html so I need those to be separate.

```
<embed src="somefile.svg" width="400" height="300"></embed>
```

Does not scale the svg, it just crops. CSS width/height doesn't work either. This there a way to do this similar to images?

Comment: What browser? What version of html? Quirks mode?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

okay, apparently you can just use svg in an img tag

```
<img src="somefile.svg" width="200"/>
```

[And it works in IE9+, FF4+, Chrome4+, Safari4+, Opera 9.](http://caniuse.com/svg-img)

Comment: if you want to use <embed> then you need to specify the 'viewBox' attribute on the <svg> element to tell it that you want it to resize to fill the area you want. The <img> element automatically constructs that viewBox for you if it's missing.

Comment: One other point to note with the difference between `embed` and `img` is that the former will allow script embedded in the svg to run, whereas the image tag wont -- at least not at the moment in FF and Chrome -- a security feature most likely.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem - in IE, not Chrome. I found that scaling (instead of cropping) would occur if the svg-file internally had a viewBox-attribute on the svg tag.